# how to cache locks for synchronizing access to domain objects

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a domain object say an Account representing user's account. Now I want that access to account should be synchronized.

```
public void operate(Account account123)
    synchronized(account123){
    }
}
```

Assume that Hibernate is being used to fetch Account. It is possible that multiple sessions retrieve the same account ie account 123 manifested as multiple objects

How do I ensure that multiple threads get access to same Account object when trying to manipulate account123?

Answer (score 0):

By using database locks and transactions instead of Java's `synchronized`. You're approaching the solution in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, you need something that is called a transaction when talking about databases.

In other words: you need a guarantee that different processes do not run in parallel and create data inconsistencies.

Especially in layered applications, the layer to do that is the **database** (that is one of the *core* features of databases to offer such services).

Alternatively, it is (sometimes) possible to build such logic within higher layers; but that is A) harder and B) much easier to get wrong.

So ideally, you look into the underlying database and the mechanisms that this component is providing to you.

Your current code works if there is always only than **one** JVM executing that method - as the *synchronized* blocking only works within that JVM process. Another JVM would not be blocked, thus data inconsistency.

Comment: Let me put it this way : I have some in memory operations to do related to a particular entity on an event E1. When I am performing these operations for that entity(A), it is possible to that some other event occurs related to same entity(A) say E2. Now operations for E1 and E2 should be synchronized and thus I would like to lock entity A. Hence I would want to cache that lock for entity A.